# ejabberd 17.01 1st message is lost on reconnection

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I have ejabberd 17.01 with offline push notification working.

App (XMPPFramework for iOS) Goes background and gets disconnected and I see jabbered logs "Waiting for resumption of stream for "

Message is sent from other client and Notification is received in background (Apple VoIP Push) and app gets connected to server ... 1st Message is not received in the app and 2nd message is received in same scenario

What is being missed by me.

Comment: you have enabled stream management on ejabberd server and XMPPFramework ?

Comment: yes its enabled on both side fro Mobile and Server